# Dataset of faces without background

Tags: data-request, images, faces

I am looking for a set of pictures that contain only the face part of the human head (no or even background), i.e. frontal upright images (like below).

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate why it's not answer by one of the questions with the tag "faces" http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faces

Comment: @philshem ,  I am looking for only face-part, nothing else, this is usually done before pre-processing.